How to determine which is the primary drive in C++?
I want to find out on which hard drive my OS is installed (for now on Windows). I figured out how to match the physical drive to the model, but since "C:" is not always on drive 0, I would appreciate some help on this.
This is what I have so far:
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

int main() {
    HRESULT hres;

    // Initialize COM library
    hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" 
                  << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize security
    hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL, 
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
    );

    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x" 
                  << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI 
    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;
    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,             
        0, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);
 
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object. Error code = 0x" 
                  << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    // Connect to WMI namespace
    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
         _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), 
         NULL,                    // User name
         NULL,                    // Password
         0,                       // Locale             
         NULL,                    // Security flags
         0,                       // Authority        
         0,                       // Context object
         &pSvc                    // IWbemServices proxy
    );
    
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" 
                  << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    // Set security levels on the proxy
    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
       pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
       RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
       RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
       NULL,                        // Server principal name 
       RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
       RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
       NULL,                        // client identity
       EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
    );

    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" 
                  << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"), 
        bstr_t("SELECT DeviceID, Model FROM Win32_DiskDrive"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        std::cout << "Query for disk drives failed. Error code = 0x" 
                  << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Get the data from the query
    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;
    
    while (pEnumerator) {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if(0 == uReturn) {
            break;
        }

        VARIANT vtDeviceID;
        VARIANT vtModel;

        // Get the value of the DeviceID and Model properties
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"DeviceID", 0, &vtDeviceID, 0, 0);
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Model", 0, &vtModel, 0, 0);
        std::wcout << "Device ID : " << vtDeviceID.bstrVal << ", Model : " << vtModel.bstrVal << std::endl;
        VariantClear(&vtDeviceID);
        VariantClear(&vtModel);

        pclsObj->Release();
    }

    // Cleanup
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}

The output for me is:
Device ID : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE5, Model : Microsoft Virtual Disk
Device ID : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3, Model : NORELSYS 1081 SD USB Device
Device ID : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2, Model : ADATA SX8200PNP
Device ID : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0, Model : CT480BX500SSD1
Device ID : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE4, Model : NORELSYS 1081 TF USB Device
Device ID : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1, Model : ADATA SP550

My current OS is actually on PHYSICALDRIVE2. So how do I determine this programmatically?
Thank you in advance!
Edit: While I don't think the purpose should matter (especially on SO where everybody is so focused on brevity), I want to read the serial number for security validation. However, since the order of SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive is unknown (in my case a virtual disk which does not have a serial number), I can't rely on that.
Edit2: I was able to get more hard disk data. Now what is left is match the hard drive:
Disk Information Dump:
Model: ADATA SX8200PNP
Serial Number: 2Jxxxxxxxxxx        _00000001.
Interface Type: SCSI
Media Type: Fixed hard disk media
Connected as: \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2


What do you mean for primary drive? I think you should think the purpose, and then adapt for it. "Primary drive" seems that you are very windows (or DOS or CP/M) focused). So: where to put temporary files? The home of current user? Where to put configuration files?  (so the few places you can usually write, the rest is probably restricted on most OS)

Voting to reopen. The question isn't about getting the drive letter. It's about getting the physical disk number. Note that a volume can span multiple physical drives (e.g. due to striping). You can get all the physical disks for a volume with IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS.

I don't know the specific, but isn't it possible to use the drive letter to get the volume GUID, and then use the GUID to get the information you want? Should probably be possible using plain Winapi functions, without WMI queries.

Can you use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getwindowsdirectorya?redirectedfrom=MSDN ?

Suppose you have a thin bootloader that lets you connect to a network and boot windows off that.  What is the OS drive?

@RaymondChen Hmm, unfortunately I was not able to get it to work. What would an implementation look like, assuming the drive is a local "C:"?

@Markstar you need get disk number ? in this question ? win8+ only solution is ok ? or you want xp/win7 too ?

@Someprogrammerdude : Hmm, I tried using GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPointW(L"C:\\", volumeName, ARRAYSIZE(volumeName)), but had no success. I'm not experience with Windows-specific programming.

@Eljay I'm not sure how to make this work, yes, I got the correct Windows path using GetWindowsDirectoryA(winPath, MAX_PATH). I then tried std::wstring query = L"SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition WHERE Dependent LIKE '%DeviceID=\"" +   std::wstring(systemDriveLetter.begin(), systemDriveLetter.end()) + L":\"'"; but eventually I could not get it to work and it exceeded my limited abilities.

@RbMm Windows 11 would be fine for now. Yes, I realize there are some edge cases, but a solution that works for 90% of the Windows systems would be enough for now.

@Markstar ok, i post solution for win8+. we can open L"\Device\BootPartition" (or L"\Device\SystemPartition" on win 10+) and query disk id. STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER more simply variant if assume volume on sigle disk.

This answer shows how to get physical disk(s) from a logical disk drive.

@RaymondChen this answer not correct. Code use fixed size structure and assume that volume have only 1 extent

we can open system volume/partition (but not file/directory on volume) and query it for disk number via IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER or IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS if assume that volume on more than one disks (i not test, what in this case IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER return)
in windows 8+ we can use L"\Device\BootPartition" for open volumeon system disk. or L"\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\BootPartition" if you want use CreateFileW instead NtOpenFile
begin from windows 10 possible use also L"\Device\SystemPartition" (note - BootPartition != BootPartition this is different volums, but both is on the same disk must be, i guess.
also exist  L"\\?\BootPartition" and L"\\?\SystemPartition" begin from win10+ . so possible use this names instead L"\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\BootPartition" for CreateFileW
after we get disk number(s) - we can say send IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY to it for get what is in your "Model" string. or we can get list of all disks, via CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW with &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK and than query disk number for every disk with IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER and than we can get more properties via CM_Get_Device_Interface_PropertyW
on win7 exist problem, how get path/open system volume. no BootPartition link exist. possible open \SystemRoot link and then use NtQueryObject with ObjectNameInformation for it and then NtQueryInformationFile with FileNameInformation for get device path.
extern const volatile UCHAR guz = 0; // /RTCs must not be set

NTSTATUS GetSysDrive(PCWSTR psz)
{
    UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &ObjectName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    HANDLE hFile;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&ObjectName, psz);
    NTSTATUS status = NtOpenFile(&hFile, SYNCHRONIZE, &oa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdn;

        if (0 <= (status = NtDeviceIoControlFile(hFile, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, 0, 0, &sdn, sizeof(sdn))))
        {
            PrintDiskInfo(sdn.DeviceNumber);
        }

        union {
            PVOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS pvde;
            PVOID buf;
        };
        PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
        ULONG cb = 0, rcb = sizeof(VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS);
        do 
        {
            if (cb < rcb)
            {
                if (rcb > 0x4000)
                {
                    status = STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR;
                    break;
                }
                cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
            }

            status = NtDeviceIoControlFile(hFile, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS, 0, 0, buf, cb);

            rcb = offsetof(VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS, Extents) + pvde->NumberOfDiskExtents * sizeof(DISK_EXTENT);

        } while (STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW == status);

        NtClose(hFile);

        if (0 <= status)
        {
            if (ULONG NumberOfDiskExtents = pvde->NumberOfDiskExtents)
            {
                PDISK_EXTENT Extent = pvde->Extents;
                do 
                {
                    PrintDiskInfo(Extent->DiskNumber);
                } while (Extent++, --NumberOfDiskExtents);
            }
        }
    }
    return status;
}

NTSTATUS PrintDiskInfo(ULONG DiskNumber)
{
    WCHAR sz[32];
    if (0 >= swprintf_s(sz, _countof(sz), L"\\GLOBAL??\\PhysicalDrive%u", DiskNumber))
    {
        return STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR;
    }

    UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &ObjectName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    HANDLE hFile;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&ObjectName, sz);
    NTSTATUS status = NtOpenFile(&hFile, SYNCHRONIZE, &oa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY spq = { StorageDeviceProperty, PropertyStandardQuery };

        union {
            PSTORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR psdd;
            PVOID buf;
        };
        PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
        ULONG cb = 0, rcb = sizeof(STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR);
        do 
        {
            if (cb < rcb)
            {
                if (rcb > 0x4000)
                {
                    status = STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR;
                    break;
                }
                cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
            }

            status = NtDeviceIoControlFile(hFile, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, 
                IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &spq, sizeof(spq), buf, cb);

            if (cb < (rcb = psdd->Size))
            {
                status = STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW;
            }

        } while (STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW == status);

        NtClose(hFile);

        if (0 <= status)
        {
            DbgPrint("[%u]: %hs%hs [%hs]\n", DiskNumber, 
                psdd->VendorIdOffset ? (PSTR)psdd + psdd->VendorIdOffset : "",
                psdd->ProductIdOffset ? (PSTR)psdd + psdd->ProductIdOffset : "",
                psdd->ProductRevisionOffset ? (PSTR)psdd + psdd->ProductRevisionOffset : "");
        }
    }

    return status;
}

GetSysDrive(L"\\Device\\BootPartition");// win8+
GetSysDrive(L"\\Device\\SystemPartition");//win10+


win32 api version:
extern const volatile UCHAR guz = 0; // /RTCs must not be set

inline HANDLE fixH(HANDLE hFile)
{
    return hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ? 0 : hFile;
}

inline ULONG BOOL_TO_ERROR(BOOL f)
{
    return f ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
}

void PrintDiskInfo(ULONG DiskNumber)
{
    WCHAR sz[32];
    if (0 >= swprintf_s(sz, _countof(sz), L"\\\\?\\PhysicalDrive%u", DiskNumber))
    {
        return ;
    }

    if (HANDLE hFile = fixH(CreateFileW(sz, 0, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0)))
    {
        ULONG dwError;

        STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY spq = { StorageDeviceProperty, PropertyStandardQuery };

        union {
            PSTORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR psdd;
            PVOID buf;
        };
        PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
        ULONG cb = 0, rcb = sizeof(STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR);
        do 
        {
            if (cb < rcb)
            {
                if (rcb > 0x4000)
                {
                    dwError = ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR;
                    break;
                }
                cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
            }

            dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(DeviceIoControl(hFile, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &spq, sizeof(spq), buf, cb, &rcb, 0));

            if (cb < (rcb = psdd->Size))
            {
                dwError = ERROR_MORE_DATA;
            }

        } while (ERROR_MORE_DATA == dwError);

        CloseHandle(hFile);

        if (NOERROR == dwError)
        {
            DbgPrint("[%u]: %hs%hs [%hs]\n", DiskNumber, 
                psdd->VendorIdOffset ? (PSTR)psdd + psdd->VendorIdOffset : "",
                psdd->ProductIdOffset ? (PSTR)psdd + psdd->ProductIdOffset : "",
                psdd->ProductRevisionOffset ? (PSTR)psdd + psdd->ProductRevisionOffset : "");
        }
    }
}

void GetSysDrive(PCWSTR lpFileName)
{
    if (HANDLE hFile = fixH(CreateFileW(lpFileName, 0, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0)))
    {
        STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdn;

        if (DeviceIoControl(hFile, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, 0, 0, &sdn, sizeof(sdn), &sdn.PartitionNumber, 0))
        {
            PrintDiskInfo(sdn.DeviceNumber);
        }

        union {
            PVOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS pvde;
            PVOID buf;
        };

        ULONG dwError;

        PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
        ULONG cb = 0, rcb = sizeof(VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS);
        do 
        {
            if (cb < rcb)
            {
                if (rcb > 0x4000)
                {
                    dwError = ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR;
                    break;
                }

                cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
            }

            dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(DeviceIoControl(hFile, IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS, 0, 0, buf, cb, &rcb, 0));

            rcb = offsetof(VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS, Extents) + pvde->NumberOfDiskExtents * sizeof(DISK_EXTENT);

        } while (ERROR_MORE_DATA == dwError);

        CloseHandle(hFile);

        if (NOERROR == dwError)
        {
            if (ULONG NumberOfDiskExtents = pvde->NumberOfDiskExtents)
            {
                PDISK_EXTENT Extent = pvde->Extents;
                do 
                {
                    PrintDiskInfo(Extent->DiskNumber);
                } while (Extent++, --NumberOfDiskExtents);
            }
        }
    }
}
GetSysDrive(L"\\\\?\\globalroot\\Device\\BootPartition");// win8+
GetSysDrive(L"\\\\?\\BootPartition");//win10+
GetSysDrive(L"\\\\?\\SystemPartition");//win10+


Thank you for taking the time to write a reply! I was not able to compile it, though, as I miss the right imports, I think. Here is what I have: Windows.h, wintern.h, ntddsci.h, wchar.h, stdio.h. What am I missing?

@Markstar you can use CreateFileW insted NtOpenFile and DeviceIoControl instead NtDeviceIoControlFile

For the win32 api, I got undefined errors for DbgPrint and RtlPointerToOffset, so I added: #define RtlPointerToOffset(B, B1) ((ULONG)((ULONG_PTR)(B) - (ULONG_PTR)(B1))) and replaced DbgPrint with std::format. After that it compiled, but I did not get any output.

@Markstar - but I did not get any output. This is not serious. You need under debugger look what happens. And you wrong define RtlPointerToOffset

@Markstar and you can check that both binary BootDevice[NT].exe and BootDevice[32].exe correct work

Again, thank you for taking the time writing all of this up. Your compiled code obviously works (though it prints the firmware version instead of serial number), but I can't compile it and therefore can't test it further. Am I right to assume that the line #include "../inc/stdafx.h" points to a common directory where are your Windows-related libraries are included (like Windows.h, stdio.h, etc.)? Also, what is _NT_BEGIN and _NT_END? TEB_ACTIVE_FRAME, TEB_ACTIVE_FRAME_CONTEXT, etc. are not recognized, despite including winternals.h.

@Markstar STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR have SerialNumberOffset too, so not hard print it to, if it exist. and yes, i use my own macros from other gits. but you can take win32 vesion of code. you can change c++ code for more confortable for you. i paste only POC how do this. and you in RtlPointerToOffset confuse order. and mandatoty use debugger for step over code

Am I right to assume that the line #include "../inc/stdafx.h" points to a common directory where are your Windows-related libraries are included yes

Sorry, this is just not readable (at least not for me). This is highly customized C-code with all kinds of typedefs and other personal adjustments that go beyond what I can decipher.

Your question was in what ? Hiw find drive number ? I paste the code. You task, not compile and build my code, but this.

Again, thank you so much for all your effort. You are making the world a better place by helping idiots like me. I really do appreciate it very much. However, this is like a first grader asking how to calculate 5*9 and you giving me a college book. It's clear I'm the stupid one but also, you are making this way to complicated. SO is about asking questions and writing answers that are clear and can be easily reprodued. I am often criticized by not being clear - your answer is definitely not easy to reproduce.

@Markstar I have provided a code that shows how to get the disk number(s) for the system volume. Your task is to understand its essence, from the Windows point of view, not C++. And based on this, write your own code, the one you like best or find convenient. And not take my code down to the symbol and try to use it as is. Many do not write specific code at all, but describe what needs to be done. Your task is to understand the meaning of the code, so that you yourself can write it and change it as needed
